# tomcat server buffers unwanted data

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, sapui5

I'm running a SAPUI5-Project in Eclipse at a Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost and write data from SQL-Database to a Json-File. Out of this Json-File I create a model for my project. This Json-File is written every time the application is started, but when I start it multiple times on an already running server it does not create the model out of the new written file, but out of the former file which which is internally buffered.
Can someone tell me how to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you buffer your existing json file to your application? did you close the connection after you stream?

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely your browser cache caching your files (including your json files).
If you do an "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" by clicking F12 in Chrome and then right clicking on the Refresh Tab you can clear the cache and check if this is the issue.